# reading multiple files with glob duplicates columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, glob

I'm trying read many txt files into my data frame and this code works below. However, it duplicates some of my columns, not all of them. I couldn't find a solution. What can I do to prevent this?

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

dfs = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(map(functools.partial(pd.read_csv, sep='\t', low_memory=False),
                    glob.glob(r'/folder/*.txt')), sort=False))
```

Let's say my data should look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JXyY.png)

But it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bqwo.png)

I don't want my columns to be duplicated.

Comment: Please provide some input and output to trace the problem effectively.

Comment: what do you mean by duplicate? Do you mean that the input from one file appear multiple times?  does the list resulting from 'glob.glob(r'/folder/*.txt')' have the desired contents?
It might be helpfull to split the step by first creating the list and iterating through it and throwing out a warning for duplicate columns so you can see where things go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you give us a bit more information? Especially the output of `dfs.columns` would be useful. I suspect there could be some extra spaces in your column names which would cause pandas to differ between those.

Also you could try dask for that:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

dfs = dd.read_csv(r'/folder/*.text, sep='\t').compute()
```

is a bit simpler and should give the same result

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to remove the duplicate columns that my code creates. Normally it shouldn't duplicate any columns and I should have 52 columns but I have 58 columns instead.

Comment: Could you provide the output of dfs.columns? It might be your csv contain 'A' and 'A ' and so it looks the same but the column names are different. Are the values also the same in the duplicated columns or is always half of them missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to think about the concat process as having two possible outcomes. By choosing the axis, you can add new columns like the example (I) below or as new rows illustrated in example (II). `pd.concat` lets you do this by setting the axis to either 0 (rows) or 1 (columns).

Read more in the excellent documentation: [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

**Example I:**

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob(r'/folder/*.txt')], axis=1)
```

**Example II:**

```
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob(r'/folder/*.txt')], axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to remove the duplicate columns that my code creates. Normally it shouldn't duplicate any columns and I should have 52 columns but I have 58 columns instead.